# How can I set libraries in "Other linker flags" with CMake?

Tags: xcode, cmake

I am trying to generate a Xcode project with cmake, but I can't define "Other linker flags" in project settings.
I have used "target_link_libraries" but it doesn't work.
Any clue? 
What I want to do is to define which libraries must be included on linking. If I do manually, I put "-lopencv_core" for example.

Comment: That's what `target_link_libraries` is for, so I'd guess that there was something wrong in the way it was used.

Comment: Did you specify the libraries by fullpath? Perhaps you need to use link_directories() as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *target_link_libraries* should handle it for you. If you aren't already using the [FindOpenCV.cmake](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FindOpenCV.cmake) module to locate the libraries that is likely the problem and you should try that next. To do this, first get the FindOpenCV.cmake file and place it on your project path (typically {project_dir}/cmake/Modules) and add the following line to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
```

This will tell CMake to use the custom FindOpenCV.cmake when resolving libraries. Then add:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( PROJECT_NAME_HERE ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Although you shouldn't need to you can set linker flags via [CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables).